# IOS 10/plist/LSApplicationQueriesSchemes

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

I have been receiving a "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fb" error when trying to open Facebook from my app.

Apple as of 9.0 apparently requires a plist entry in `LSApplication` for url  schemes in order to implement the canOpenURL method.  Running IOS10.3, I don't see the `LSapplication` option in my Plist.

Did Apple change plist key?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: The key is (and always has been) [`LSApplicationQuerySchemes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right Click on info.plist file, then open it as Source code.

Please below code inside it.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fbapi20130214</string>
    <string>fbapi20130410</string>
    <string>fbapi20130702</string>
    <string>fbapi20131010</string>
    <string>fbapi20131219</string>
    <string>fbapi20140410</string>
    <string>fbapi20140116</string>
    <string>fbapi20150313</string>
    <string>fbapi20150629</string>
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fb</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150128</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150218</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150305</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Your info.plist will see like this.

[image]

Let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Queried URL Schemes` in the plist.

[image]

[image]